# If $UT=TU $, why is the range of $U $ invariant under $T $?

Tags: linear-algebra

My Linear Algebra book says the following:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $T$ be a transformation, which commutes with another transformation $U$. Then the kernel and range of $U$ are invariant under $T$.

I can understand why the kernel must be invariant. But I don't understand why the range must follow this. Any help in understanding this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $U(T(v))=T(U(v))$ for all $v\in V$.  Now suppose that $w=U(v)$ for some $v$.  Then $T(w)=T(U(v))=U(T(v))$.  Thus $T(w)$ is also in the range of $U$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y$ be in the range of $U$. Then there is $x \in V$ such that $y = Ux$. Note that $$Ty = TUx = UTx \in \operatorname{range}(U).$$ So $T(\operatorname{range}(U)) \subseteq \operatorname{range}(U)$.